# Use wurfl api in kohana 3.2

Tags: api, kohana, wurfl

How to import wurfl api in kohana 3.2?

[here is the api](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/apis.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create wurfl folder in the modules
2. Copy the source code to the module folder
3. Enable the module in the bootstrap.php

More information: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/modules
Sometimes it's easier to write a small wrapper class around the vendor API.
Take a look for example at https://github.com/banks/kohana-email to see how it's done.

Comment: But where to write this:
include_once './inc/wurfl_config_standard.php';